# Add a new field to every document and give it the value of another field of the same document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I know how to add a field with the same value to every document. What I want to do is add a "title_lower" field that has the same value as "title" but in lowercase.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55a3907b8c5bf672f4ad319b"),
    "title" : "Oracle",
    "title_lower" : "oracle",
    "status" : "active",
    "company_default" : true,
    "is_deleted" : false

}
```

I've come up with a query to add a field but cannot figure out the second part:

```
db.getCollection('group').update(
    {} ,
    {$set : {"title_lower" : "title"}},
    {multi:true})
```

Will I need to write a Javascript file for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the linked question worked for me:

```
db.getCollection('group').find().forEach(
  function(e) {
    e.title_lower = e.title.toLowerCase();
    db.getCollection('group').save(e);
  }
)
```